# Access SQL to create new record for each record in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access

**DB Structure**

```
Table: tbl_dateLog
    Field: ID (Autonumber)
    Field: dateEntry(Date Format)

Table: tbl_technician
    Field: ID (Auto number format)
    Field: fname (string format)
    Field: lname (string format)

Table: tbl_entries
    Field: ID (Auto number format)
    Field: dateID (number format)
    Field: techID (number format)
    Field: totalClaims (number format)
```

I have been searching for a solution for quite a while.  I believe the answer is simple, but it keeps eluding me.

I would like to add a new record for Today's date using Date() in tbl_dateLog. Then loop an `INSERT INTO` query that will add a new record in `tbl_entries` for each `tbl_technicians.ID`, place a zero for the `tbl_entries.totalClaims` field, and place the `tbl_dateLog.ID` in the `tbl_entries.dateID` field.

I hoped something like this would get me on the right track, but I'm sure I will need a type of JOINS to add the dateID:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_entries (techID,totalClaims) select ID, 0 FROM tbl_technician
```

I am having a lot of trouble tying this all together and searching for an answer has confused me even more. I am using Access 2016.

Comment: only one table goes between the (brackets)... the output table.  https://www.google.ca/search?q=append+query+tutorial+join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to add a new record for Today's date using Date() in
>   tbl_dateLog.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_dateLog
( 
dateEntry
) 
SELECT 
Date()
;
```

> Then loop an INSERT INTO query that will add a new record in
>   tbl_entries for each tbl_technicians.ID, place a zero for the
>   tbl_entries.totalClaims field, and place the tbl_dateLog.ID in the
>   tbl_entries.dateID field.

```
 INSERT INTO tbl_entries
(
dateID,
techID,
totalClaims
)
SELECT
(SELECT [tbl_dateLog]![ID] FROM [tbl_dateLog] where [tbl_dateLog]![dateEntry] = DATE()),
tbl_technician.ID,
0
FROM
    tbl_technician
;
```

Comment: Amazing! That worked beautifully!  It looks like nesting was the key :)